# getSelectionStart() doesn't work in android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want to get EditText selection start when user click in EditText (touch).
I do with this code :

```
int startIndex = txtMean.getSelectionStart();
```

this always return 0;

and EditText xml code:

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtMean"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:hint=""
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:scrollbars="none" />
```

my code work in android 2.* but don't work in 4.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  txtMean.getSelectionStart();
```

getSelectionStart doesn't relate to the user's last touch or click per se.  It relates to the text selection on the screen.  By default, when the user does a long click text-handles will come up, and allow the user to expand a highlighted text selection.  It's the highlighted text that refers to the selection, which is not necessarily where the user last touched.

When the user makes a text selection it becomes highlighted because the EditText will apply a SelectionSpan to the character sequence, and getSelectionStart will return the start value of this span.

Update, Solution Help:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

  // this = EditText;
  // will give you the position of the nearest chracter.    
  int offset = this.getOffsetForPosition(event.getX(), event.getY());
```

Comment: do you want the text_offset of the nearest character to the touch, or the pixel-coordinates of where you touched?

Comment: yes i want to get position of touched in text, with this position i cant automatically find touched word.

Comment: this require API 14 !

Comment: API 14 isn't that bad, 80% of devices :)  But you can get back to API 1 copying the [source-code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.getOffsetForPosition%28float%2Cfloat%29) ...several functions.

Comment: onTouchEvent() doesn't work in landscape. How to do this in landscape?